# How to save the current state of my staging area?

Tags: git

**Question:**
I added some files to my staging area. I want to temporarily save this information. How to?

**Background:**
Sometimes I perform some bigger refactorings. It only really makes sense to commit the complete result.
During this refactoring, I also make some unrelated changes which I would like to commit independently.
For example, the refactoring renamed a method. The unrelated change fixed a spelling error on one parameter of another method in the same class.
Now, assume I already added most of the files to the staging area when I realize that I forgot to commit one of the unrelated changes beforehand.
Adding the files to the staging area takes time, because I check every single file to make sure that I really only commit what I want to. So, simply removing them all from the staging area is not the solution.
What I would like to do instead:

1. Save the current state of the staging area
2. Remove all staged files
3. Stage the unrelated change
4. Commit the unrelated change
5. Re-apply the saved state to the staging area.

Is this somehow possible?

An alternate solution would be the possibility of multiple staging areas, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: There is only one staging area. And git doesn't really store it - you could do that yourself.

Comment: you probabl want to [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) and do some interactive checkout/add then

Comment: @NevikRehnel: How would git stash preserve the work I put into the existing state of the staging area?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Stash by default saves both the index and the working tree, returning your working copy to a clean state.

Comment: @NevikRehnel: But that's not what I want. I don't want a clean state of my working copy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following chain of commands should do the trick

```
git commit -m "temporary" # save current stage are as an actual commit
git commit unrelated_files -m "The other feature"
git stash # hide the rest
git rebase -i HEAD~2 # change the order of two last commits
git reset --soft HEAD^ # rollback the "temporary" commit and keep everything from that commit staged
git stash pop # and return back all initially unstaged stuff
```

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. Thanks a lot! :) And it perfectly matches my use of git. I do a lot of rebasing anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely need `git stash`

This will save your current work, and leave your directory as if you did a reset to HEAD.
You can now switch branches, do some work on another topic.

When you're ready to work on your feature again, re-apply your stashed changes with `git stash apply`

You can combine multiple stashes, `git stash list` will list them, then you can select wich one to apply, such as `git stash apply @{1}`

Edit :

As @nevik-rehnel said in the comments, you can also use interactive adding.

Unstage everything, use `git add -p` to stage the unrelated changes, commit, then restage everything.

Comment: No, this is definitly *not* what I need. I am talking about the *staging area*, not my working directory. And I don't want to change my branch either.

Comment: Git stash will save your staging area and leave a clean directory, then you can change your file, do your unrelated commit, stash apply, finish your work, and commit.

Comment: See this gist for a more detailed example : https://gist.github.com/Intrepidd/d52b7e190aec8cd29854

Comment: All changes I want to commit are already done, even the unrelated ones. `git stash` would give me a clean working copy, so there would be nothing left to commit.

Comment: Then you should probably rethink the way you commit, whenever you feel the need to work on an unrelated feature, git stash. Otherwise, you'll have to unstage the changes and this can be a pain.

Comment: Appreciate the gist. It shows exactly the problem. You need to do `echo unrelated >> hello` directly after `echo whatever >> bar` and before `git add bar` to have my scenario.

Comment: We are not talking about features here. We are talking about small fixes along the way. A little improvement on a comment here, a little bit better naming for a parameter there. Staging all other changes just to do this little improvement is not realistic, especially when we are talking about big repositories. Every stash or branch change costs about 5 minutes, because I have to close down and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Then consider interactive staging (`git add -p`). (if necessary, unstage everything,) stage the first set of (logically coherent) changes, commit, repeat.

Comment: @NevikRehnel: I already do that, that's why the current state of my staging area is som important. But interactive staging doesn't solve this problem. Assume I had a method with a parameter named `nsmgr`. The current feature I am working on is to introduce contracts into the code base, so I add a line `Contract.Requires(nsmgr != null);`. While typing that, I feel that `nsmgr` really is a horrible name and change it to `namespaceManager`. This are two unrelated changes. Now, further assume that I want to commit all of my new contracts, so I start adding files to my staging area. After adding...

Comment: ...50 files, I come across the one above. I realize that I first should have staged the line of the method signature with the changed parameter name. Interactive staging will not help me here, because I would need to stage something that is not there: `Contract.Requires(nsmgr != null);`. All I have is `Contract.Requires(namespaceManager != null);`. So, even with interactive staging, the *order* in which I stage things sometimes is important.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: First of all, consider postponing such changes after your next commit (i.e. do think about your workflow), or after adding stuff to the index. Secondly, commits can be reordered (interactive rebasing). This is really not a problem that any tool can solve for you; you'll have to split up certain dependent changes, not make a wild mix of them and expect to sort them out with Git.

Comment: @NevikRehnel: Postponing these changes is not an option. It wouldn't match my workflow. Additionally, think about the [boy scout rule](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1235624&seqNum=6), because that's what I am applying here. If I would postpone those changes, they would never happen. Reordering commits doesn't help me either, because currently I have only *one* commit where I should have two.

Comment: @NevikRehnel: That's actually what I like so much about git and its interactive staging: I can work the way *I* want - and not my VCS - and still end up with meaningful commits. Well, at least most of the time, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you save it as a branch and start a new branch

Comment: How to save a branch without affecting master?

Comment: E.g. because it wont work when you are editting commits during an interactive rebase.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work:

- git commit -m "temp"
- git stash -u
- git reset HEAD^
- git stash save "MeepMeep!"
- git stash pop stash@{1}

Answer (score 0):

**This is a way to save the state without interrupting your current work.**

```
git add . # OR whatever you want to add
git commit -m "saved state"
git log
```

Copy the hash of the last commit to your clipboard, paste it to your notes.

```
git checkout -b saved_State_Holder  
git cherry-pick <copiedHash>
git checkout <yourOriginalBranch> 
git reset --soft HEAD~1 # To keep your commit history clean
git reset # to unstage the changes
```

Now whenever you want to access that state, simply open your notes, copy the desired hash, and run this:

```
git cherry-pick <copiedHash> # applies that state
git reset --soft HEAD~1 # Optional if you want to pick and choose changes
git reset
```

Comment: This is a full answer.